# jqplot : tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'} shows duplicate intervals on x-axis

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am plotting graphs using **"jQplot" (jquery.jqplot.js and jquery.jqplot.css)**

For this I have written following code:

```
$tfsGraphNodes= "[1,4],[2,2],[3,21],[4,61],[5,71],[6,10]";
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [[{/literal}{$tfsGraphNodes}{literal}]],
                        {title: 'Applicant Behaviour'
                                    , series: [{color: 'green'},
                                , {label: 'Applicant Trend'}]
                                    , legend: {show: true}
                            , highlighter: {showTooltip: true}
                            , axes: {
                                xaxis: {
                                    tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'}
                                },
                            }
                        });
```

To get integer value on x-axis I have used `tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'}` and I am getting the value as **(0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,.....)**

But I want the interval not to be duplicated.

For better understanding I am attaching the image:

[image]

Comment: Try to specify **tickInterval** (in xaxis options) to 1

Comment: @AnthonyLeGovic I have specified the same but it seems not working .

Comment: Please see my answer and attached Fiddle link on it. TickInterval (as mentionned) seems to answer your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using %d as a format string I got the same problem. When I replace '%d' by '%#d' problem got solved.

```
axes: {
 xaxis: {
  tickOptions: {formatString: '%#d'},
  tickInterval: 1
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify **tickInterval: 1** in xaxis options :

```
axes: {
 xaxis: {
  tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'},
  //Comment or un-comment to see what happens on xaxis's ticks
  tickInterval: 1
 } 
}
```

Please see working Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/eKWCg/), you can comment/un-comment tickInterval line to see how it changes xaxis's ticks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add min and max options to make the duplicates go away:

```
xaxis: {
    tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'},
    tickInterval: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
}
```